# async_send data not sent

Tags: c++, sockets, boost, boost-asio

[disclaimer] I am new to boost.

Looking into boost::asio and tried to create a simple asynchronous TCP server with the following functionality:

1. Listen for connections on port 13
2. When connected, receive data
3. If data received == time, then return current datetime, else return a predefined string ("Something else was requested")

The problem: 
Although, I accept the connection and receive the data, when transmitting data using async_send, although I receive no error and the value of bytes_transferred is correct, I receive empty data on the client side.

If I try to transmit the data from within handle_accept (instead of handle_read), this works fine.

The implementation: 
I worked on the boost asio tutorial found [here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_63_0/doc/html/boost_asio/tutorial.html#boost_asio.tutorial.tutdaytime3):
Instantiate a tcp_server object, that basically initiates the acceptor and starts listening. as shown below:

```
int main()
{
    try
    {
        boost::asio::io_service io_service;
        tcp_server server(io_service);
        io_service.run();
    }
    catch (std::exception& e)
    {
        std::cerr << e.what() << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

and in tcp_server:

```
class tcp_server
{
public:
    tcp_server(boost::asio::io_service& io_service)
        : acceptor_(io_service, tcp::endpoint(tcp::v4(), 13))
    {
        start_accept();
    }

private:
    void start_accept()
    {
        using std::cout;
        tcp_connection::pointer new_connection =
            tcp_connection::create(acceptor_.get_io_service());

        acceptor_.async_accept(new_connection->socket(),
            boost::bind(&tcp_server::handle_accept, this, new_connection,
                boost::asio::placeholders::error));
        cout << "Done";
    }
    ...
}
```

Once a connection is accepted, I am handling it as shown below:

```
void handle_accept(tcp_connection::pointer new_connection,
        const boost::system::error_code& error)
{
    if (!error)
    {
        new_connection->start();
    }

    start_accept();
}
```

Below is the `tcp_connection::start()` method:

```
void start()
{

    boost::asio::async_read(socket_, boost::asio::buffer(inputBuffer_),
        boost::bind(&tcp_connection::handle_read, shared_from_this(),
            boost::asio::placeholders::error,
            boost::asio::placeholders::bytes_transferred));

    /* the snippet below works here - but not in handle_read 
    outputBuffer_ = make_daytime_string();

    boost::asio::async_write(socket_, boost::asio::buffer(outputBuffer_),
        boost::bind(&tcp_connection::handle_write, shared_from_this(),
            boost::asio::placeholders::error,
            boost::asio::placeholders::bytes_transferred));*/
}
```

and in `handle_read`:

```
void handle_read(const boost::system::error_code& error, size_t bytes_transferred)
{
    outputBuffer_ = make_daytime_string();
    if (strcmp(inputBuffer_, "time"))
    {
        /*this does not work - correct bytes_transferred but nothing shown on receiving end */
        boost::asio::async_write(socket_, boost::asio::buffer(outputBuffer_),
            boost::bind(&tcp_connection::handle_write, shared_from_this(),
                boost::asio::placeholders::error,
                boost::asio::placeholders::bytes_transferred)); 
    }
    else
    {
        outputBuffer_ = "Something else was requested";//, 128);
        boost::asio::async_write(socket_, boost::asio::buffer(outputBuffer_),
            boost::bind(&tcp_connection::handle_write, shared_from_this(),
                boost::asio::placeholders::error,
                boost::asio::placeholders::bytes_transferred));
    }
}
```

The `handle_write` is shown below:

```
void handle_write(const boost::system::error_code& error,
    size_t bytes_transferred)
{
    if (!error)
    {
        std::cout << "Bytes transferred: " << bytes_transferred;
        std::cout << "Message sent: " << outputBuffer_;
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "Error in writing: " << error.message();
    }
}
```

Note the following regarding `handle_write` (**and this is the really strange thing**):

- There is no error
- The bytes_transferred variable has the correct value
- outputBuffer_ has the correct value (as set in handle_read)

Nevertheless, the package received at the client side ([Packet Sender](https://packetsender.com/)) is empty (as far as data is concerned).

The complete code is shared [here](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/7f39ea9e6032e61c425d1ca160a84f55).

Comment: when you say you receive empty data, do you mean that you get a completed receive of 0 bytes (eof) or does the async_read never complete? And why are you not checking the error code in your handler function?

Comment: @RichardHodges I am using "Packet Sender" application as a client. Looking at the data part of the tcp packet received, it is empty (no data part). I want to clarify, that in the code above, inputBuffer_ is correct. I am not checking for the error, because I was receiving EOF (which I guess is normal,having read the whole stream). I will check for all errors apart from EOF. I will also edit my question to include the handle_write.

Comment: be careful with asio::async_read and an eof error. the async_read free function is a composed operation. It is possible for it to indicate eof when bytes_transferred is non-zero. In this case you should accept the data and then optionally perform eof actions (if you don't, you'll get another eof error with zero bytes transferred on the next read, so it doesn't matter if you skip this optional step).

Comment: Just to clarify. My problem is not at async_read. What I receive is fine. The problem is when trying to send data from within handler_read using async_write(). The data, although appear to have been sent correctly, contain no data at the receiving end.

Comment: Worked fine for me using a bare simple python client.

Comment: @Arunmu can you please share the python client, because I really cannot get it to work. Thanks

Comment: @Lefteris http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/725c31ef858b80f8

Comment: @Arunmu Thank you very much for this... the interesting thing now is that  `sd.recv(128)` never returns. I am looking into it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the problem with the collective help of the comments provided in the question. The behavior that I was experiencing was because of the functionality of `async_read`. More specifically in the [boost asio documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_63_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference.html#boost_asio.reference.async_read) it reads:

> This function is used to asynchronously read a certain number of bytes
>   of data from a stream. The function call always returns immediately.
>   The asynchronous operation will continue until one of the following
>   conditions is true:
>
> - The supplied buffers are full. That is, the bytes transferred is    equal to the sum of the buffer sizes.
> - An error occurred.

The inputBuffer_ I was using to read the input, was a 128 char array. The client I was using, would only transfer the real data (without padding), and therefore the async_read would not return until the connection was closed by the client (or 128 bytes of data were transferred). When the connection was closed by the client there was no way to send back the requested data. This is also the reason that it was working with @Arunmu's simple python tcp client (because he was sending 128 bytes of data always).

To fix the issues, I made the following changes (the full working code is supplied [here](https://gist.github.com/kororos/7c947e4b8e1ee67be5d0c9ef42b9f724) for reference):

- In `tcp_connection::start`: I am now using `async_read_until` to read the incoming data (and use `\n` as a delimiter). The input is stored in a `boost::asio::streambuf`. `async_read` is guaranteed to return once the delimiter has been found, or an error has occurred. So there is no chance to issue multiple `async_write` concurrently.
- In `handle_read`: I have included error checking, which made it much simpler to debug.

Answer (score 1):

Complete test program (c++14). Note the handling of asynchronous buffering when responding to a receive - there may be a send already in progress.

```
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <thread>
#include <future>
#include <vector>
#include <array>
#include <memory>
#include <mutex>
#include <condition_variable>
#include <iterator>
#include <iostream>

namespace asio = boost::asio;

asio::io_service        server_service;
asio::io_service::work  server_work{server_service};

bool listening = false;
std::condition_variable cv_listening;
std::mutex              management_mutex;

auto const shared_query = asio::ip::tcp::resolver::query(asio::ip::tcp::v4(), "localhost", "8082");

void client()
try
{
    asio::io_service      client_service;
    asio::ip::tcp::socket socket(client_service);

    auto lock = std::unique_lock<std::mutex>(management_mutex);
    cv_listening.wait(lock, [] { return listening; });
    lock.unlock();

    asio::ip::tcp::resolver resolver(client_service);
    asio::connect(socket, resolver.resolve(shared_query));
    auto s = std::string("time\ntime\ntime\n");
    asio::write(socket, asio::buffer(s));
    socket.shutdown(asio::ip::tcp::socket::shutdown_send);

    asio::streambuf sb;
    boost::system::error_code sink;
    asio::read(socket, sb, sink);
    std::cout << std::addressof(sb);
    socket.close();
    server_service.stop();
}
catch(const boost::system::system_error& se)
{
    std::cerr << "client: " << se.code().message() << std::endl;
}

struct connection
    : std::enable_shared_from_this<connection>
{
    connection(asio::io_service& ios)
        : strand_(ios)
    {

    }

    void run()
    {
        asio::async_read_until(socket_, buffer_, "\n",
                               strand_.wrap([self = shared_from_this()](auto const&ec, auto size)
        {
            if (size == 0 )
            {
                // error condition
                boost::system::error_code sink;
                self->socket_.shutdown(asio::ip::tcp::socket::shutdown_receive, sink);
            }
            else {
                self->buffer_.commit(size);
                std::istream is(std::addressof(self->buffer_));
                std::string str;
                while (std::getline(is, str))
                {
                    if (str == "time") {
                        self->queue_send("eight o clock");
                    }
                }
                self->run();
            }
        }));
    }

    void queue_send(std::string s)
    {
        assert(strand_.running_in_this_thread());
        s += '\n';
        send_buffers_pending_.push_back(std::move(s));
        nudge_send();
    }

    void nudge_send()
    {
        assert(strand_.running_in_this_thread());
        if (send_buffers_sending_.empty() and not send_buffers_pending_.empty())
        {
            std::swap(send_buffers_pending_, send_buffers_sending_);
            std::vector<asio::const_buffers_1> send_buffers;
            send_buffers.reserve(send_buffers_sending_.size());
            std::transform(send_buffers_sending_.begin(), send_buffers_sending_.end(),
                           std::back_inserter(send_buffers),
            [](auto&& str) {
                return asio::buffer(str);
            });
            asio::async_write(socket_, send_buffers,
                              strand_.wrap([self = shared_from_this()](auto const& ec, auto size)
            {
                // should check for errors here...
                self->send_buffers_sending_.clear();
                self->nudge_send();
            }));
        }
    }

    asio::io_service::strand strand_;
    asio::ip::tcp::socket    socket_{strand_.get_io_service()};
    asio::streambuf          buffer_;

    std::vector<std::string> send_buffers_pending_;
    std::vector<std::string> send_buffers_sending_;
};

void begin_accepting(asio::ip::tcp::acceptor& acceptor)
{
    auto candidate = std::make_shared<connection>(acceptor.get_io_service());
    acceptor.async_accept(candidate->socket_, [candidate, &acceptor](auto const& ec)
    {
        if (not ec) {
            candidate->run();
            begin_accepting(acceptor);
        }
    });
}

void server()
try
{
    asio::ip::tcp::acceptor acceptor(server_service);
    asio::ip::tcp::resolver resolver(server_service);

    auto first = resolver.resolve(shared_query);
    acceptor.open(first->endpoint().protocol());
    acceptor.bind(first->endpoint());

    acceptor.listen();

    begin_accepting(acceptor);

    auto lock = std::unique_lock<std::mutex>(management_mutex);
    listening = true;
    lock.unlock();
    cv_listening.notify_all();


    server_service.run();

}
catch(const boost::system::system_error& se)
{
    std::cerr << "server: " << se.code().message() << std::endl;
}

int main()
{

    using future_type = std::future<void>;

    auto stuff = std::array<future_type, 2> {{std::async(std::launch::async, client),
                                                 std::async(std::launch::async, server)}};

    for (auto& f : stuff) f.wait();

}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple issues in this code. Some of them may be responsible for your problem:

- TCP has no definition of packets, so there's no guarantee that you will ever receive `time` at once in handle_read. You need a statemachine for that and to respect the bytes_transferred info. If you only have received a part of the message you need to continue at the correct offset. Or you can use asio utility functions, like reading exactly a length of bytes or reading a line.
- In addition the last point, you shouldn't really compare the received data with `strcmp`. That will only work if the remote also sends a null terminator over the connection - does it?
- You don't check whether an error happend, although that might manifest itself in other errors.
- You are possibly issueing multiple concurrent async writes if you receive multiple data fragments in a shart timespan. This is not valid in asio.
- More important, you mutate the send buffer (`outputBuffer_`) while the send is in progress. This will pretty much lead to undefined behavior. asio might try to write a piece of memory which is no longer valid.

Comment: Thanks @Matthias247 - I will look into each one of the raised points and hopefully I will get to the bottom of it. Your 2nd and 3rd bullets are straightforward, the 4th is something I will need to spend some time on. The 5th is not very clear to me, can you explain a bit further? The 1st point is clear too.

Comment: Ok, point 5: If you give the data to send to boost asio (with `boost::asio::buffer(outputBuffer_)`) asio will not copy the data and store it internally for performance reasons. It will only copy the buffer wrapper structure, which means something like the pointer to the data and the length of the data. You are responsible that the data stays alive for the whole duration of the operation. If the memory at the position that you gave asio change during the async write operation you have that undefined behavior.

Comment: If you use a std::string here you give asio the pointer the strings internal backing memory at the start of the operation. When you reassign the string (`outputBuffer_=...`) std::string will either change the data at that position or even allocate a new backing buffer and deallocate the old one. The pointer to the old one is then invalid.

Comment: Ok, I got it. I guess that this is a problem given that the tcp receive may be broken in several parts, which will then call async_write several times and outputBuffer_ will change during the subsequent calls.

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm guessing

Comment: @Matthias247 Point 1 is not true. the callback will be called only when either an error occurs or data worth the buffer size (128 bytes in this case) is read. So, it is guaranteed that "time" would be read in a single call.

Comment: @Arunmu: You are right, I mixed that up with `async_read_some`. However `async_read` with a 128bytes buffer would cause other problems, like waiting and doing nothing while `time` was already received.